# Using reflection to find classes and invoke properly

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an abstract class called `Action` which accepts a byte array and represents actions done by the client. I have several actions that are implemented from this class and they contain properties, like so:

```
[Action(ActionCode.Login)]
public class LoginAction : Action
{
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }

    public LoginAction(byte[] data)
        : base(data)
    {
        this.Username = this.ReadMapleString();
        this.Password = this.ReadMapleString();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to defind a method using the actions like so:

```
public static void Login(LoginAction action)
```

So when I receive data from the client I can handle the actions based on the code received. However, I'm not sure how to use reflection to find the method that's associated with the action. I mean, I can find LoginAction using the code under, but I can't find the method that's using LoginAction as a parameter, which is the method I want to invoke.

I want to achieve something like:

```
public void OnRecieveData(ActionCode code, byte[] data)
{
    // Using the ActionCode, call the specified action handler method.
    // Login(new LoginAction(data));
}
```

I already know how to find classes that use the ActionCodeAttribute, but I'm not sure how to invoke it:

```
static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithHelpAttribute(Assembly assembly) {
    foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HelpAttribute), true).Length > 0) {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with this design? Calling a method with an Action as parameter instead of a virtual method on the action does not seem like a proper design in the first place. And then using reflection as the primary means of invoking your program‘s functionality seems quite off. These are huge code smells and I am pretty sure there is a better design to achieve your goal. So this seems to be an XY problem here.

Comment: @Sefe Hm, I guess you're right. I added a method called "Handle" and I implement it in al my claasses. So what is the best way to map the classes that use the ActionAttribute with their ActionCode as key?

Comment: You need to explain the reasoning for this design (ie. the problem you want to solve) to see which design is appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a good reason for your design (see comments), you could find it with a bit of LINQ.

First, we need to find the type. We just get all types, filter their attributes by type (using `OfType<>`), and find the first class that has at least one ActionAttribute.

```
var type = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where
            (
                t => t.GetCustomAttributes()
                      .OfType<ActionAttribute>()
                      .Where( a => a.ActionCode == code)
                      .Any()
            )
            .Single();
```

Next to find the static member. We already know the type of the containing class. But we don't necessarily know the name. Tnen again, we do know the type of the first parameter, and that the call is static. Assuming there is always exactly one method that meets all of these criteria, we can use this:

```
var member = type
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where
            ( 
                m=> m.GetParameters()
                     .First()
                     .ParameterType == type
            )
            .Single();
```

Then we create the instance:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { data });
```

And invoke it:

```
member.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance });
```

Full example:

```
    static public void OnReceiveData(ActionCode code, byte[] data)
    {
        var type = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where
            (
                t => t.GetCustomAttributes()
                      .OfType<ActionAttribute>()
                      .Where( a => a.ActionCode == code)
                      .Any()
            )
            .Single();

        var member = type
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where
            ( 
                m=> m.GetParameters()
                     .First()
                     .ParameterType == type
            )
            .Single();

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { data });

        member.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance });
    }
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bymcLj)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do when you want to execute actions based on a code is to create a dictionary with action objects:

```
public abstract class Action {
    public abstract void Execute(byte[] data);
}

//...

Dictionary<ActionCode, Action> actions = new Dictionary<ActionCode, Action>();

//...

void ExecuteAction(ActionCode actionCode, byte[] data) {
    actions[actionCode].Execute(data);
}
```

You can populate the `actions` dictionary in an appropriate way that solves your problem. If you want to load the implementations from external libraries, you could do the following (using your existing `GetTypesWithHelpAttribute` method):

```
void PopulateActions(Assembly assembly) {
    foreach(Type actionType in GetTypesWithHelpAttribute(assembly)) {
        var codeQry =
            from attribute in type.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<ActionAttribute>()
            select attribute.Code;
        ActionCode code = codeQry.Single();
        Action action = (Action)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        actions.Add(code, action);
    }
}
```

That assumes you apply the `HelpAttribute` to the actions you want to load. You can also directly look for the `ActionAttribute` and drop the `HelpAttribute` altogether.

This solution keeps the reflection code where it belongs: when you load the actions from an external source. Your execution code is free from reflection, which improves maintainability and performance. You can also combine the dynamic load with static actions you add without reflection from your main module.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to define methods using the same name in the same class for each of the different type of actions:

```
void Handle(LoginAction action);
void Handle(FooAction action);
void Handle(BarAction action);
```

And you've constructed your ...Action object of the right type, you can call it using:

```
Handle((dynamic)action)
```

You can even afford the explicit case if you just do

```
dynamic dynAction = action;
Handle(dynAction);
```

And yes, the correct overload will be determined at runtime based on the type of the action.